# jQuery Datepicker for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker script:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

When I want to initialize this script for two inputs, it works only for the first one. How to use it for both inputs?

```html
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: have a class to all the inputs which need a datepicker

Comment: $('.your-class').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });

Comment: in the first place, you can't have more than one id

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just change all `id` to `class`.

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" class="datepicker">

$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

also can use

```
$(function() {
  $( "input[name^=MyDate]" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Comment: I read through several threads on this that suggested super complicated ways to achieve this - yours took me about .5 seconds and worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"` will display: `YYYYYYYY-MM-DD` remove the extra `yy` to display correct format. Update to: `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"`

Comment: An id may only be used once on a page, and clearly jQuery adheres to that spec.

Comment: it's helped me! THX

Answer (score 6):

Tired of repeating this, but still, am repeating it once more. `id`s have to be unique. So, use this:

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" class="datepicker">
```

with

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It isn't valid to have duplicated IDs.  You should add a class instead:

```html
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" class="datepicker" id="datepicker1">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" class="datepicker" id="datepicker2">
```

Then you can do:

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Access datepicker function by Name:

```js
$(function() {
    $('[name="MyDate1"]').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add classes on the fly if input fields are dynamically generated, such as in Django templates.

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" id="datepicker1">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" id="datepicker2">
```

Get input fields using #id and add a class

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).addClass('datepicker');
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" id="datepicker1">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" id="datepicker2">
```

Just get input fields using #id and apply datepicker.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Access date picker by id

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" id="datepicker1">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" id="datepicker2">

$(function() {
  $( "input[id^=datepicker]" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
});
```

OR access date picker by name:

```
<input type="text" name="MyDate1" id="datepicker1">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" id="datepicker2">

$(function() {
   $( "input[name^=MyDate]" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code like this and work properly in multiple field form:

Add this code before loop:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.mydatepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

And this line is in loop:

```html
<div class="control-group form-group" style="padding: 5px;">
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="bi bi-calendar2-minus" style="color: #FF6600;"></span>
    Input Date
    <input name="myDate$i" type="text" class="form-control mydatepicker" id="myDate$i" required ="true" placeholder="Contoh: 2022-11-25" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" style="border-radius: 3px; padding:10px;"/>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

And just give the forms the id's:
datepicker
datepicker2
datepicker3