# Splitting jQuery datepicker into seperate Day / Month / Year fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

So I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin for Wordpress, which I believe utilises the jQuery datepicker to generate its date fields (please correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is, rather than a single field, can I split the user's input box into the three separate elements (Day / Month / Year), whilst still using the datepicker to check whether the date exists (to prevent the user from choosing February 31st for example)?

Basic JSFiddle which hopefully explains what I mean... http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/n908n2g3/1/

Basic datepicker code 'cause I've been told to include code D:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Just looking for any advice/help :) Is something like this even possible? Do I need to be applying new JavaScript if I have to manually split it into three drop-down fields?

Comment: That kinda defeats the purpose of a date picker.  You can very easily adjust the number of days in the "day" field based on the selected month in the  "month" field.  AFAIK, date pickers came along to help solve the data entry problems caused by combining the three date fields into one.  Combining three fields into a single date field is just a much better user experience IMO.

Comment: True, I could do that, but then my concern would be leap years... is there a simple bit of maths to calculate whether a year is a leap year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker for multiple inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803518/jquery-datepicker-for-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. There is a event-handler(onSelect) for datepicker, that is called as soon as a date is selected:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {

            date = date.split(/\//g);

            var day = date[1];
            var month = date[0];
            var year = date[2];

            $('#day').val(day);
            $('#month').val(month);
            $('#year').val(year);

        }   
});
```

Furthermore I would make the three input-fields readonly. So an user can not modify the values that were inserted by datepicker.

```
<p><input id="day" type="text" placeholder="Day" readonly/>
<input id="month" type="text" placeholder="Month" readonly/>
<input id="year" type="text" placeholder="Year" readonly/></p>
```

Another approach would be to add an datepicker to each element:

```
attachDatepickerToFieldById("#day");
attachDatepickerToFieldById("#month");
attachDatepickerToFieldById("#year");

function attachDatepickerToFieldById(id){

    $(id).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {

            date = date.split(/\//g);

            var day = date[1];
            var month = date[0];
            var year = date[2];

            $('#day').val(day);
            $('#month').val(month);
            $('#year').val(year);

        }   
    });

}
```

Now when you click on a field a datepicker appears at it and after selection a date all three fields are set accordingly. In this case you can remove the original input-field.

Comment: Whilst I see what that's doing, it's not quite what I was aiming for... Ideally I don't want to be using the single datepicker field at all, and just have three drop-downs for the user to select from. Whilst I could use jQuery to change the number of days based on the month (so if they select February, they can only select 1-28 for the day), my concern is leap years.