# Getting datepicker function to work on all rows in table

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

I am having an issue where I can only get the Datepicker calendar function to work only on the 'ModfiyStatusDate' field of my table.  Here is my table definition and actual function.

```
          $(function () 
          {
            $("#ModifyStatusDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
              });
          });



         <tr>
             <td align="center">  
               <input style="width:50px;" type="checkbox" id="selectedSched" 
                        name="selectedSched" value="<c:out value="${schedcombo}"/>"/>  
             </td> 

             <td id="ModifyScheduleNumber"><c:out value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" /></td>
             <td id="ModifyYear"><c:out value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" /></td>
             <td id="ModifyCreationDate"><c:out value="${row.getCREATION_DATE()}"/></td>
             <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 5px;"><c:out value="${row.getNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS()}"/></td>
             <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 5px;"><c:out value="${schedTotl}"/></td>
             <td><select style="width:45px;" size="1" id="ModifyStatus" 
                 name="ModifyStatus_<c:out value="${schedcombo}"/>" class="combosmall">
                 <c:forEach items="${ModifyList}" var="statusValue">
                      <option value="${statusValue}"
                      <c:if test="${statusValue == UpdCMDStatus}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                                 >${statusValue}</option>

                 </c:forEach>
                 </select> </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:85px" id="ModifyStatusDate" 
                    name="ModifyStatusDate_<c:out value="${schedcombo}"/>" 
                       type="text" class="texttable" value="${row.getSTATUS_DATE()}"/>
                       </td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.getAPPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE()}"/></td>
     </tr>
```

I have looked at similar issues and it seems like I have to change my 'ID' attribute to make it unique like the 'name' attribute that I needed for the servlet processing.  Is that true or can I still work with just using what I have?  If I do have to modify the ID then why is it only working on the first row currently?

Thanks

Comment: Use a class as a selector, give all input fields which should work with the picker the same class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker for multiple inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803518/jquery-datepicker-for-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the calendar to show up on all of the rows.  I modified my function to show:

```
       $("input[id$='ModifyStatusDate']").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      });
```

Now I have the issue where if I try to modify the date on the 2nd row for example it updates the date on the 1st row all the time.  So like usual I solved one problem with another problem.

Comment: This is because an ID is for unique elements, Using it twice wont work.

Comment: If I add an unique ID to the field, will the field update the value in the specific row or do I still have to add code in the 'OnSelect' function (I think) to ensure that.   Also do I need to modify the datePicker function call to do something like 'id^=ModifyStatusDate to get all of them?    Thanks

Comment: As I already mentioned in my first comment - use a class. In fact this question is already answered (a few times). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803518/jquery-datepicker-for-multiple-inputs

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sorry I saw something from another thread and tried this.   I guess I didn't consider this a multiple ID since it is only field on a table.  I know that I shouldn't create two input boxes or text areas or buttons with the same name.

Using the classes worked in getting the pop up calendar and output is going into the right row but now I need to figure out why the data is showing screwed up.  If the value was originally '2016-02-10' and I select '2016-02-01' it shows up '20162016-02-01'.   I have to look and see what clears the field and updates it I guess.